# Rails - will_paginate says "variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I have this query:

```
@cars = Car.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order(created_at: :desc).group_by { |r| r.created_at.to_date }
```

and in the view:

```
= will_paginate @cars
```

But I am getting this error (rendered in `site#index`):

```
The @site variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?
```

I've also tried to update the query this way:

```
@cars = Car.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).group_by { |r| r.created_at.to_date }
```

But the error is still the same.

How to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: afterall is @site or @cars?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
@car_paginator = Car.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).order(created_at: :desc)
@cars = @car_paginator.group_by { |r| r.created_at.to_date }
```

Then change the line with the pagination in your view:

```
= will_paginate @car_paginator
```

The problem is: When you use the `paginate` method the results is not a normal array or database relation but an object that has some extra information like `@size`. If you run `group_by` on that you remove that extra attributes and return a plain hash.