# undefined method `total_entries' will_paginate groupby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I'm using the following query with pagination, however, group_by(&:name) is causing the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `total_entries' for #<Hash:0x00007fa05e369a60>):
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, but here is the query:

```
data = Posts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).joins("INNER JOIN d ON a.id = d.a_id").select("a.*, d.*").group_by(&:name)

respond_to do |format|
  format.any
  format.json {
    render :json => {
        :totalCount => data.total_entries,
    }
  }
```

it works fine without group_by(&:name). any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28143287/4988918) help?

Comment: Oh it works actually, thank you